# Drag calculation from pressure + shear stress distribution

Tags: pressure, drag, stress-strain

If I know the shape of a body, pressure and shear stress distribution over it, how can I calculate the total drag acting on it ? More exactly, can I calculate it this way:

Drag = [Pressure difference on the body (along x-direction) + x-shear difference (along x-direction)] * projected area of the body